# When transferring from non-Schengen EU airport to a Schengen airport, do I need to go through security at the connection airport?

Tags: airports, airport-security, connecting-flights, hel

I'm travelling from the UK (non-Schengen, Heathrow) to Finland (Vantaa). I have a very brief transfer window and I've noticed on Flight Radar that the flight is always nearly late by 20 minutes, which cuts it a lot shorter. I have a connecting flight from Helsinki to Oulu, and I am 100% sure I have to go through at least passport control but I'm not sure about security too. I only have carry-on luggage but it could still take precious time.

The Finnair [website seems a bit ambiguous](https://www.finnair.com/gb/gb/information-services/at-the-airport/finnair-ticket-office-and-transfer-service-desks) about it, making it sound like I only need to go through passport control, or [through security if I'm travelling TO a non-Schengen airport](https://www.finnair.com/gb/gb/information-services/at-the-airport/security-control), but doesn't mention flying in FROM one.

Could someone enlighten me on this? I'm stressing pretty hard.

I already have boarding passes for both.

Comment: You will certainly have to go through passport control in Helsinki. I don't know the layout of the airport for whether you can do an airside transit, with or without a security check.

Comment: Well the passport control I'm certain of, but that's easy as its done by automated machines. I'm mostly curious about a separate security check that could take time.

Comment: I don't know about Helsinki in particular, but in my experience, the vast majority of hub airports in Schengen are set up such that passengers who _arrive from_ a country with "trusted" airport security (with includes all EU countries) do not need to be security screened again for connecting flights. [There are exceptions, though.]

Comment: I'm hesitant to put this down as an answer, because I lack personal experience, but according to [the Finavia website](https://www.finavia.fi/en/airports/helsinki-airport/airport/terminals/transfer) you don't have to go through security. Would you mind sharing the planned connection time? People have different estimates of what "short" is, and while 45min-20min would be really stretching it, 1:10h-20min would still be ample of time in HEL.

Comment: @Sabine it's 45 minutes, so I'm pretty worried, but mostly due to the fact most of the flights appear late.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have previously done tight transfers from Heathrow to a local Finnish airport, via Helsinki - likely very similar flights to your own.

You need to go through passport control (automated gates seemed quickest, sometimes they also have a dedicated "short connection" lane). However, you do not need to go through a security check.

Finnair will put the gates for upcoming flights on the screen of your first flight, make a note of where you need to go and head straight there without delay and you should be fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this situation today: Coming from a Non-Schengen flight and transferring to a Schengen flight at Helsinki airport. Yes, going through security control was mandatory.

Comment: This depends on where you came from. Non-EU arrivals seem to trigger security control while intra-EU (but non-Schengen) arrivals (such as the UK) don’t necessarily.